# copying text from notepad to ubuntu console

Tags: 20.04

I have a question!
In my notebook I have prepared a file with some txt content.
Currently I have created my actual file in ubuntu called flights.txt.
Now I would like the contents of the notepad file to be in my ubuntu creator's flights.txt file and then load it into the mcedit editor. How can I do it? is there any commands for this? Attempts to copy `Ctrl + Shift + C from notepad and paste Ctrl + Shift + V` to Ubuntu console do not work. I tried with the command `cat> logi.txt` and at this point I can enter the content I would like to get in this file. I just don't know how to transport this content from an ordinary notebook to this file without having to enter it manually because the content is quite large.
Please help

This is a fragment of a homework assignment, we got the .txt file saved in the Windows notebook, it has over 500 lines, the first step in the command is to create a file in Linux which will contain the content of this file from the notebook that we received from the lecturer.
Windows and Ubuntu on one computer, as above, the actual content I received is in the Windows notebook and the file that I will create using the Ubuntu console is to contain the contents of this file from the Windows notebook. This content is quite extensive, so I would like to know if it is possible to copy this content, or if I will have to rewrite over 500 lines. Ubuntu was installed on a Windows 10 laptop from the Windows Store after previously unchecking the programs control panel and the option to enable the Windows subsystem for Linux

Comment: It isn't really clear from your question what your setup is. I assume you mean the Windows text editor program called "Notepad". Are Windows and Ubuntu running on the same computer? If so, in what way? Ubuntu in WSL on Windows? Or Windows's notepad running in Wine under Ubuntu or in a virtual machine? Or are they on different computers, and you're connected via SSH or some other way? `cat file1.txt >> file2.txt` will append file1.txt to the end of file2.txt, but that's assuming both files/filesystems are accessible in the same way.

Comment: This is a fragment of a homework assignment, we got the .txt file saved in the Windows notebook, it has over 500 lines, the first step in the command is to create a file in Linux which will contain the content of this file from the notebook that we received from the lecturer.

Comment: Windows and Ubuntu on one computer, as above, the actual content I received is in the Windows notebook and the file that I will create using the Ubuntu console is to contain the contents of this file from the Windows notebook. This content is quite extensive, so I would like to know if it is possible to copy this content, or if I will have to rewrite over 500 lines. Ubuntu was installed on a Windows 10 laptop from the Windows Store after previously unchecking the programs control panel and the option to enable the Windows subsystem for Linux

Comment: I've never actually used WSL, but from what I can tell from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1083962/windows-linux-subsystem-accessing-files-outside-of-ubuntu), you should be able to access the Windows file in somewhere like `/mnt/c/Users/Paulina/filename.txt` or some subfolder like `/mnt/Users/Paulina/Desktop/filename.txt` depending on exactly where you saved it. So you should be able to do `cat /mnt/Users/Paulina/(something)/filename.txt >> flights.txt` (if you're in the same folder as flights.txt, or else put in the path to it as well). Be sure to use two `>>` not one.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on your any text editor.

and then,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> on your any console or terminal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what executes the command, but the text is not pasted
I don't know if I got the question right, I probably have a text written in the Windows notebook, it is over 500 lines, I would like to copy it to the ubuntu console, this text is to be in the linux txt file that I would like to create with this content

Comment: @PaulinaProcek if your linux bash can access windows file, you can read/write from there. else if bash cannot access windows file, you can create a symlink like `ln -s /mnt/d/Directory/to/file /home/user/data`